# I'm curious: has anyone build a HAT and sold it commercially? Looking for experiences

Tags: sensor, hat

Has anyone build a HAT and sold it commercially?

Looking for experiences on how to the production and distribution is.

Has anyone ideas on how to promote a HAT when you built it?

I find there is no good solution for sensors out there...

Comment: Welcome -- but we are not a discussion style forum and open-ended invitations to brainstorm around a general topic do not suit the format.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works, and read *["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*